# Render data containing number sign(#) in Handlebar

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have a handlebar template that displays a company address.
Whenever the address contains the number sign(#), the rendering stops and HTML is incomplete.
I also tried adding a simple HTML value Company# and it doesn't load as well.
I'm using handlebar 4.7.6. Any insights will do. Thank you.

Handlebar Template

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
     <h4>Address: <small>{{company.address}}</small></h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
     <h4>Description: <small>{{company.description}}</small></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Compiling handlebar

```
var templateHtml = fs.readFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(), 'pdfTemplate.html'), 'utf8');
var template = handlebars.compile(templateHtml);
var html = template(treatmentJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

To escape special HTML syntax, you can use `{{{variable}}}` instead of the usual double curly brace sign. This should solve your problem.

[Reference](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping)